# How to discard incorrect options??

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

> Suppose $f$ and $g$ are entire functions $g(z)\neq 0 \forall z\in
> \mathbb C$.If $\vert f(z)\vert \le \vert g(z)\vert $,then we can
>   conclude that-
>
> - $f(z)\neq 0 \forall z\in C$
> - $f$ is a constant function.
> - $f(0)=0$
> - for some $M\in \mathbb C$,$f(z)=Mg(z)$.

Solution:

Since,$f(z)$ and $g(z)$ are entire functions and $g(z)\neq 0\implies \frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$ is also entire.

Now,$\vert f(z)\vert \le \vert g(z)\vert \implies \frac{\vert f(z)\vert}{\vert 
 g(z)\vert} \le 1. \tag{*}$So,by Liouville's theorem $f/g$ is constant.

**Making $4$ option true.**

Now,since $g(z)\neq 0 z\forall C$ and is entire so,$g(z)$ must be a non-zero constant.

**Thus, by $f/g$ is constant ang $g $ is non-zero constant we'll get $f$ is constant.**.Making option $2$ correct.

But the only correct option is $4$.

How to discard options 1,2,3??

**Compilation of arguments suggested by José Carlos Santos and kamills**

> - Since,$f(z)=Mg(z)$.But,$M$ can be equal to zero.So,$f(z)=0$,making option $1$ false.
> - Taking,$f(z)=e^z;g(z)=1+e^z$,then $\vert f(z) \vert \le \vert g(z) \vert$.But,$f(z)$ is not constant,making option $2$ false.
> - take $f(z)=e^z$,then $f(0)=1$,making option $3$ false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't discard the second or the third options. After all, your $M$ can very well be equal to $0$. And, by the way, that proves that you *can* discard the first option.

Comment: :But the only correct option  is 4.

Comment: @PKStyles Then you forgot some hypothesis. Or don't you agree that if you take $f(z)=0$ and $g(z)=e^z$, then every option except the first one are fulfilled?

Comment: :I  got you'r point.Actually, i misread my notes,which leads to misunderstanding of options...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely convinced that $g$ has to be constant. After all, the hypothesis is only that $|f(z)| \leq |g(z)|$ on $\mathbb{C}$; it's not assumed that $g$ is bounded. Although it is entire, Liouville's Theorem can't be used, so option 2 isn't necessarily correct.

Option 1 can also be discarded, since even though $g$ isn't zero, $f$ could be at some point of $\mathbb{C}$. Similarly, there's no reason to believe that $f(0) = 0$, discarding option 3.

Comment: :sorry!!,i've written half true statement,the correct statement is A non-zero constant function is the only rational entire function which do not have any zero in $\mathbb C$

Comment: Are you given that g is rational?

Comment: :No, actually i misread  my notes

Comment: Gotcha. Yes, so that is another way of writing Liouville's theorem. But g isn't necessarily rational (there's a comment below mentioning $g(z) = e^z$), so Liouville's theorem can't be applied.